# Named SqlParameters not being recognized

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to access a stored procedure from a C# program, and incredibly enough, I am getting

> Procedure or function 'procedure_name' expects parameter '@agency',
>   which was not supplied.

Except that it *is* supplied:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp);
cmd.Connection = conn;

SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter();
parm.ParameterName = "@agency";
parm.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
parm.Size = 3;
parm.Value = txtAgency.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
```

The stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]
(
    @agency varchar(3)
    , @subagency varchar(1)
    , @start datetime
    , @end datetime
)
AS
```

I have done similar stored procedure calls for years and years without this problem occurring with perfectly valid and correct calls.  This stored procedure works just fine when executed from Sql Management Studio, by the way.

Note that I have changed the order of the parameters and get the same response for the very first parameter, whichever it is.

When I have run this under the debugger in Visual Studio I do confirm that the parms have the necessary values in the expected places.

Comment: @GrantWinney, as you recognized, Marc_s beat you to the draw, but thanks for the comment-with-answer, for that is what I saw first and did the facepalm about.

Comment: @GrantWinney, the so-called duplicate was asked at virtually the same time this one was asked (can't see the exact timestamps yet).  Why didn't you mark the OTHER one as the duplicate?

Comment: I know it's not anything against me, and it certainly doesn't cause any pain, as such, @GrantWinney, but if I were to tell you that it hurt my feelings, would you care?  :-)  Don't worry, I don't *really* feel slighted!  Just clowning around to disguise my pain at the general state of the world.

Comment: No, no!  I like things just the way they are, @GrantWinney, trust me!  As long as my reputation increases it is all good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **tell** your `SqlCommand` that it's dealing with a stored procedure - like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp);
-- add this line
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I fell victim to this.  I've coded these calls hundreds of times -- and coded them correctly!  Now I feel stupider than ever.  Thanks for not hooting at me.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: errare humanum est - humans do make mistakes - just try to not make the same once twice :-)

Comment: You're too late -- I've made this one before.  Obviously not recently enough that I recognized the error when it popped up.